Clustered Linux servers showing different results when viewing CIFS mount
We have an MFT application running on two AmazonLinux 2023 EC2 instances. These two nodes both mount to several different CIFS shares on various on-prem Windows file shares.
Many of the jobs set up in the MFT application depend on "seeing" new files on these mount points.
What we are seeing is that, the nodes do not always get the same results when listing existing files from these CIFS filesystem mounts. On one node, listing a particular directory might show 197 files, while listing the same directory on the other node might show 194 files.
These mounts are connected via autofs (though not sure if that is relevant).
The current options for the mounts as set in the mapping files are:
-fstype=cifs,nounix,noperm,cache=none,credentials=/etc/.credentials-file,uid=501,gid=100,noserverino,hard

Restarting autofs usually "resets" this and then both nodes get the same results from listing the same remote directories.
It is worth noting that these same nodes also mount several NFS volumes and we do not see this phenomenon...though I believe all NFS volumes are in AWS (though some are in third-party AWS accounts).
We have, in the past, set the buffer size in the mount options, but that also did not seem to resolve the issue.
Also, not sure if it's relevant, but I believe that whenever this phenomenon occurs, the directory in question is multiple levels deep and not in a top-level (or nearly top-level) directory on the file system share. By "many" that is something like 5 or more levels deep in the remote directory structure. In some cases there are whitespace characters, but not always.
We have tried running tcpdump on the Linux nodes and we have been unable to find anything that indicates what is causing the issue.
At this point, I am at a loss as to what to look at next. Being an intermittent issue, we have no way to cause the symptom to occur and it can sometimes occur within a few hours of adjusting settings and sometimes it takes a couple of weeks for the symptom to occur again.
Any thoughts or ideas on how we can dig into this further and figure out what is going on, that would be great.
